# For...next в языке R

Tags: r

Совсем недавно стал работать в R.

Каким образом, в таблицу можно добавить дополнительный столбец и заполнить его 1 с некоторым шагом?

Пример заполненной таблицы:

```
1   1
2   
3   1
4   
5   1
6   
7   1
8   
9   1
```

Answer (score 3):

С шагом 1 совсем просто:

```
iris$new <- c(1, NA)
```

С шагом n:

```
n <- 2
iris$new <- c(1, rep(NA, n))
```

Используя `data.table`, можно модифицировать таблицу без перезаписи:

```
library(data.table)
iris <- data.table(iris)
iris[, new := c(1, rep(NA, 2))]
```

Comment: что-то не получается...
если мой пробный скрипт такой:
> b<-data.frame(seq(1,10,1))
> data<-seq(1,10,1)
> b<-data.frame(data)
> print(b)
то как добавить столбец справа и расставить там 1 с первой строки с шагом 2?

Answer (score -1):

такой вариант сработал (при помощи data.table)

> library(data.table)
>   a<-seq(1,10,1)
>   b<-data.frame(a)
>   c<-data.table(b)
>   c[, new := c(1, rep(NA, 1))]
>   print(c)